# Remove object from array with specific index (MongoDB, NodeJS, React)

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, object

I have app with devices-array which have objects
with device_name and device_id. I'd like to remove specific device depending which device user want's to remove from devices array.

I've already tryied to findIndex and indexOf -methods, but it return's undefined for request. How to access  device depending which device user want's to remove?

```
deviceController.js

'use strict'

import Users from '../models/userModel.js'


deleteDevice: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { device } = req.body.device.device_id

      const dev = await Users.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }).populate('device')

      const devs = dev.device //devices

      const index = devs.findIndex(req.body.device)
      const devic = devs.slice(index, 1)

      await Users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user.id }, { device: devic })
      res.json({ msg: 'Deleted success' })
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
    }
  }

export { deviceControl }
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faEdit, faTrash } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { Container, Table } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { showErr, showSuccess } from '../utils/notifications/Notification'
import {
  fetchAllUsers,
  dispatchGetAllUsers
} from '../../redux/actions/usersAction'
import '../../index.css'

//initialize device
const initialState = {
  device: { device_name: '', _id: '', device_id: '' },
  err: '',
  success: ''
}

function AllDevices() {
  //authentication
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
  //token
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.token)
  //set data
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)

  //users
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users)

  const { device_name, device_id, err, success } = data
  //loading
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  //authentication
  const { user, isAdmin } = auth
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setData({ ...data, [name]: value, err: '', success: '' })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAdmin) {
      fetchAllUsers(token).then((res) => {
        dispatch(dispatchGetAllUsers(res))
      })
    }
    if (isAdmin || user) {
      setData(initialState)
    }
  }, [token, user, isAdmin, dispatch, loading])

  const updateDeviceName = async () => {
    try {
      if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to rename this device?')) {
        await axios.patch(
          `/device/edit/${data.device._id}/${data.device.device_name}`,
          {
            device: { device_name, device_id }
          },
          {
            headers: { Authorization: token }
          }
        )
      }
      setData({ ...data, err: '', success: 'Updated Success!' })
    } catch (err) {
      setData({ ...data, err: err.response.data.msg, success: '' })
    }
  }

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    if (device_name) updateDeviceName(device_name)
  }

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    try {
      if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this device?')) {
        setLoading(true)
        await axios.patch(
          `/device/delete/${data.device}`,
          { device: data.device },
          {
            headers: { Authorization: token }
          }
        )
      }
      setData({ ...data, err: '', success: 'Updated Success!' })
    } catch (err) {
      setData({ ...data, err: err.response.data.msg, success: '' })
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h5 className='m-5'>
        {' '}
        <Link to='/'>
          <i className='fas fa-undo-alt'></i>Takaisin
        </Link>
      </h5>
      <Container fluid='sm'>
        <div>
          {err && showErr(err)}
          {success && showSuccess(success)}
          {loading && <h3>Loading.....</h3>}
        </div>
        <Table bordered hover variant='light' responsive>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Nimi</th>
              <th>Laite</th>
            </tr>
            {/* Loop through user details */}
            {users.map((p) => (
              <tr>
                <td>
                  {p.name}
                  <br />
                  {p.email}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {p.device.map((d) => (
                    <div>
                      <div
                        className='d-flex-inline'
                        style={{
                          position: 'relative',
                          width: '170px'
                        }}
                      >
                        {' '}
                        <input
                          type='text'
                          style={{
                            fontSize: '16px',
                            width: '100px'
                          }}
                          defaultValue={d.device_name}
                          name='device_name'
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />{' '}
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                          style={{
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: '3px',
                            right: '70px',
                            zIndex: '2'
                          }}
                          icon={faEdit}
                          title='Edit'
                          onClick={() => handleUpdate(d.device_name)}
                        />{' '}
                      </div>

                      <div
                        className='d-flex'
                        style={{
                          position: 'relative',
                          width: '100px'
                        }}
                      >
                        <input
                          type='text'
                          style={{
                            fontSize: '14px',
                            width: '200px',
                            color: '#333'
                          }}
                          defaultValue={d.device_id}
                          disabled
                          name='device_id'
                        />{' '}
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                          style={{
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: '3px',
                            right: '3px',
                            zIndex: '2'
                          }}
                          icon={faTrash}
                          title='Trash'
                          onClick={() => handleDelete(d.device)}
                        />{' '}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export default AllDevices
```

```
const deviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  device_id: { type: Number, required: true },
  device_name: { type: String, required: true }
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please enter your name!']
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please enter your email!']
    },
    device: [deviceSchema, { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }],
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please enter your password!']
    },
    days: { type: Date },
    role: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0 // 0 = user 1= admin 3=visitor
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
)

const Users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

export default Users
```

```
import { deviceControl } from '../controllers/deviceController.js'
import express from 'express'
import auth from '../middleware/auth.js'
import authAdmin from '../middleware/authAdmin.js'

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/device', auth, authAdmin, deviceControl.getUsersAllDevices)

router.post('/device', auth, authAdmin, deviceControl.getUsersAllDevices)

router.patch('/device/delete/:id', auth, authAdmin, deviceControl.deleteDevice)

router.put('/add_device', auth, deviceControl.addDevice)

router.patch('/device/edit', auth, deviceControl.updateDeviceName)

export default router
```

Comment: Please create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can check it and test out

Answer (score 0):

try using JS [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

```
const removeDevice(devices, id) => {
  return devices.filter(device => device.id !== id)
}
```